# When building in xcode12 release mode, a crash occurs when opening the app with a universal link

Tags: swift, xcode

When building in xcode12 release mode,
a crash occurs when opening the app with a universal link.

like
`myApp://`

The problem does not occur in xcode11.

---

Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x005b07d01caaf670 -> 0x000000501caaf670 (possible pointer authentication failure)
VM Region Info: 0x501caaf670 is in 0x1000000000-0x7000000000;  bytes after start: 275358873200  bytes before end: 136957987215

this is a bug report in the testflight bug report

Comment: You should provide more details. Did you get any meaningful error messages?

Comment: @benjamiWen  i modified it